# Calculate strides to run up stairs

Tags: c#

The staircase has between 1 and 50 flights of stairs, inclusive. Each flight of stairs has between 5 and 30 steps, inclusive. StepsPerStride is between 2 and 5, inclusive. It takes 2 strides to turn around on the landing.

**Example:**

Input: {15, 15}, StepsPerStride: 2, Returns: 18

There are two flights with a landing in between. 8 strides to get to the first landing, 2 strides to turn around, and 8 more strides to get to the top makes 8+2+8=18 strides

```
 public class RunUpTheStairs : IRunUpTheStairs
    {
        public ushort CalculateTotalStrides(byte[] stairs, byte stride)
        {
            if (!this.Validate(stairs, stride))
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("stairs and / or stride are out of range.");
            }

            byte numberOfStrides = 0;
            foreach (byte flight in stairs)
            {
                numberOfStrides += (byte)(flight / stride);

                if (flight % stride != 0)
                {
                    numberOfStrides++;
                }
            }

            ushort totalStrides = (ushort)(numberOfStrides + (stairs.Length - 1) * 2);
            return totalStrides;
        }

        private bool Validate(byte[] stairs, byte stride)
        {
            if (stairs.Length < 1 || stairs.Length > 50)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (stairs.Any(nextFlight => nextFlight < 5 || nextFlight > 30))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return stride >= 2 && stride <= 5;
        }
    }
```

I am posting this for code review. Any improvements for performance will be much appreciated too!

Answer (score 3):

You have one exception for different parameters and I believe it is wrong. You should separate validation of each argument and also use clear message instead of just "something is out of range".

Also I recommend to use `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` only for arguments that represent single value that is out of range. `Length` of an array argument is not an argument itself. Some invalid value inside the array is not an argument too.

So define validation methods

```
private bool IsStairsSizeValid(byte[] stairs)
{
    return stairs.Length >= 1 && stairs.Length <= 50;
}

private bool AreStairsValuesValid(byte[] stairs)
{
    return stairs.All(nextFlight => nextFlight >= 5 && nextFlight <= 30);
}

private bool IsStrideValid(byte stride)
{
    return stride >= 2 && stride <= 5;
}
```

and then use them

```
if (!IsStairsSizeValid(stairs))
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Stairs has invalid size.", nameof(stairs));
}

if (!AreStairsValuesValid(stairs))
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Stairs contains invalid value.", nameof(stairs));
}

if (!IsStrideValid(stride))
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(stride), stride, "Stride is out of range.");
}
```

Also you should always check arguments of reference type on `null` in public API:

```
if (stairs == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(stairs));
}
```

---

I don't see any reason the `numberOfStrides` variable should have `byte` type. You use it within integer calculations so there is no point in `byte`. Declare it as `int` and remove casting to `byte` in the loop.

```
int numberOfStrides = 0;
foreach (var flight in stairs)
{
    numberOfStrides += flight / stride;
```

---

If you have division and remainder calculation for the same values it can be better to use `Math.DivRem` method:

```
numberOfStrides += Math.DivRem(flight / stride, out var remainder);
if (remainder != 0)
{
    numberOfStrides++;
}
```

---

There is no need to store result of calculations to local variable if you return it immidiately. So you can write just

```
return (ushort)(numberOfStrides + (stairs.Length - 1) * 2);
```

Comment: I dont think that Math.DivRem supports byte.

Comment: @YawarMurtaza Can you explain what do you mean?

Comment: Math.DivRem(flight / stride, out var remainder); wont work because flight is byte so is stride, unless i cast them into ints.

Comment: @YawarMurtaza You should read about implicit casting a bit :)

Comment: Apologies, you are right, I was not using the correct overload - thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

I don't agree with the [other answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/174637/59161) becasue those exceptions are not better then the original one as they also do not inform me about the valid range for any of the parameters.

For example this message is unnecessary *stairs and / or stride are out of range.* as I already know that from the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. What I don't know and actually want to know is what is the valid value?

This means you should not use a single validation method for all parameters but check each one separately and throw an exception with a helpful message.

In case of the `stairs` it should be:

```
if (stairs.Length < 1 || stairs.Length > 50)
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
        paramName: nameof(stairs),
        message: $"{nameof(stairs)} must be between 1 and 50.");

}
```

where `1` and `50` should be some constants.

Answer (score 1):

#### Input validation

Instead of making the validation method return a `boolean` which the caller still has to act on, it would be simpler to put the validator method fully in charge of validation and throw exceptions by itself.

```
private void ValidateInput(byte[] stairs, byte stride)
{
    ValidateRange("length of stairs", stairs.Length, 1, 50);

    foreach (var stair in stairs)
    {
        ValidateRange("stair", stair, 5, 30);
    }

    ValidateRange("stride", stride, 2, 5);
}

private void ValidateRange(String name, int value, int min, int max)
{
    if (value < min || max < value)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
            paramName: name,
            message: $"{name} must be between {min} and {max}.");
    }
}
```

#### Conditions on ranges

Conditions on ranges are a bit easier to read when their terms are in increasing order. Instead of:

> ```
> return stride >= 2 && stride <= 5;
> ```

Consider:

```
return 2 <= stride && stride <= 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `byte` for numberOfStrides.  Then `ushort` for totalStrides.
The two strides to turn on the landing is going to put it over the edge?

Comment: If I use ushort instead of byte for numberOfStrides it works. I just want to keep the memory usage to the minimum.

Comment: You are allocating an ushort anyway so no memory is saved.

Comment: ushort is 16-bit integer whereas int is  32-bit integer.

Comment: I know what ushort is and you are allocating it.